# Must Spark finish reading all input files before performing operations?

Tags: apache-spark

Let's say I've got 10 input files, each several GBs in size, and I'm trying to read them into an RDD and perform a map/reduce operation.

Obviously, the `reduce` stage will have to wait until all 10 files are completely loaded.  But can the `map` stage begin sooner?

In other words, does Spark create each partition piecemeal and then immediately start running the `map` operation on that partition's data ... or does it wait until all the data is fully loaded from all 10 files and only then kick off the `map` operation on all partitions simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have reason to believe that spark is waiting for all the files to be loaded in memory before starting any transformation ?

Spark does lazy evaluation. So when you give it set of files it will figure out how many jobs are required and read the files sequentially process it and dump output. It wont try to load whole file in memory before starting processing.